# Geopolitics *and* economics?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, vocabulary, politics

What word or concise phrase in English covers international politics and economics?  My Merriam-Webster defines geopolitics as "politics, esp. international relations, as influenced by geographical factors."  Is there a word that covers this AND international money issues?

Comment: Not specially. But *geopolitics* includes important elements of macro-economics, it is the broader word. In many contexts, *geopolitics* should cover what you need, or *international relations*.

Comment: To a first approximation, *international politics* these days is just a ***subset*** of [*global economics*](http://www.businessweek.com/global-economics)

Comment: *geopolitics* definitely includes international economics and finance, as well as humanitarian/sociological and military considerations. Merriam and Webster are both inaccurate to limit the term to geographical factors. It's much more about the human beings than it is about their incidental geo-location. For example "Palestinians" and "Israelis" share the same geographical factors but their geopolitical position is markedly different, largely because of non-geographical factors.

Comment: Although neighbors, Palestinians and Israelis hardly share the same geographical factors. Different access to and control of local natural resources, particularly water; consequences of living on one side or the other of the boundary and the wall that separate them; access to proximate some-time allies: all these are profoundly geographic. So are their strong similarities of language, climate, and the stress of living in a small land next door to a hostile neighbor.

Answer (score 1):

An **economist** will tell you: geopolitics + economics = economics.

A **diplomat** will tell you: geopolitics + economics = geopolitics.

A **public policy** expert will tell you geopolitics + economics = [geoeconomics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoeconomics).  (Thanks to @JoanPederson.)

A **politician** will be thinking: geopolitics + economics = a very convenient distraction from local economics.

A **law student's** eyes will go misty thinking: geopolitics + economics = exam day from hell.

Answer (score 0):

**Geoeconomics** is well suited for reference to situations of the present day and the past two decades or so, which do not so easily fit the notions of the classical geopolitics of the previous 100 years or so. Although sometimes considered a subset of geopolitics, geoeconomics is considered by others to be a successor to it. This shift can be justified by the increasing awareness in the general public of international economic issues and their effects on our lives, such as the expansion of globalized manufacturing, multinational corporate structures, and free-trade agreements (whether for better or worse), and of the extent to which such issues permeate international relations.

The geographic factors inherent in the prefix "geo" include absolute location, relative location (on which side of a boundary or barrier, for instance), natural resources of the place(s) or region(s) in question, extent of territory, usable access to the sea, contiguity (how well do you and your neighbors get along?), state-specific similarities and differences in international policy and macroeconomic circumstances, distribution of assets and challenges, and movement of capital and ideas.