# Georeferencing vs. Geo-referencing

Tags: orthography

---

What would be the correct spelling:

1. *georeferencing* or
2. *geo-referencing*?

---

I'm writing my PhD on the topic and would prefer to write correctly, of course. Some research I've conducted already:

#### Merriam-Webster

The Merriam-Webster online dictionary does not know the term: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/georeferencing (as of today).

However, looking at somewhat similar terms, I can see no clear pattern:

- *geo-economics* (perhaps a more common word than georeferencing): the website notes, that *geoeconomics* is less common compared to *geo-economics*
- *geospatial* (more closely related to the topic of georeferencing): dash form is not mentioned

#### Encyclopedia of Database Systems

Uses *georeferencing* (without dash): https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-39940-9_181

The same author also published a book in 2009 titled *Georeferencing* https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/georeferencing .

#### Scientific field

The authors use both spellings; however, most are non-native English speakers. Additionally, it is not always necessary that their texts were checked by a professional before publication. Following are two lists of some selected publications grouped together by their usage of the word georeferencing.

Using 1. option:

- (2018) https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8453694
- (2019) https://jgcc.geoprevi.ro/docs/2019/10/jgcc_2019_no10_3.pdf
- (2020) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343849821_Georeferencing_in_the_context_of_building_information_modelling/citations?latestCitations=PB%3A351907369 (my paper, which also shows my inclination towards option 1. as the correct answer)

Using 2. option:

- (2012) https://www.repo.uni-hannover.de/handle/123456789/4740
- (2020) https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/12/12/1928
- (2021) https://www.researchgate.net/publication/351907369_A_Common_Approach_to_Geo-Referencing_Building_Models_in_Industry_Foundation_Classes_for_BIMGIS_Integration

Similarly, *geo-information* is used by an international journal from the field https://www.mdpi.com/journal/ijgi

Comment: Somehow related content in a different question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152930/geopolitics-and-economics/154084#154084

Comment: You’ve done an excellent job here in showing us that you've already researched this without coming to a clear resolution.

Comment: 'However, scientific and technical writing styles omit the hyphen between most prefixes, especially prefixes that are not words themselves. The following list of prefixes that normally are not followed by a hyphen is adapted from _Scientific Style and Format by the Council of Biology Editors_: aero / after / ante / anti / ... / geo / ... ' [[MIT Style recommendations](http://www.mit.edu/course/21/21.guide/hyphen.htm)] So this can't be wrong from a global perspective; however, it is quite conceivable that another institution likes the hyphen after _geo_. Check your in-house style guide.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and the valuable link to the MIT recommendations. 

Meta question: seeing that the question is closed, there is no outstanding action needed by me, right?